# How do you make a loop with switch statements in c++?

Tags: c++, loops, visual-c++, while-loop, switch-statement

Bear with me, I'm still pretty new to C++...

So my dilemma is that I have a menu for 2 games, both within their respective switch statement/cases. The code works, but it'll close the game once it's done. I can't for the life of me figure out how to loop back to the main menu that I made to select the games again.

My code is the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string name;
  int choice; //the choices for the menu
  char sym; //part of the menu
  int number = rand() % 10 + 1; //sets number to a random number between 1-10
  int digit; // part of the math game
  bool menu = true;
  int guessNum; //number that user guesses
  int i; //loop variable
  bool guessRight = false;
  char answer = 'y';



  /questions omitted
  while (menu){ //start of loop and will come back here after each game finishes
    cout << setfill(sym) << setw(55);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\t Welcome," << ' ' << name << endl;
    cout << "Please choose a number from the following options:" << endl; //Gives the user the options to input using numbers.
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\t1. Play the math game!" << endl;
    cout << "\t2. Play the guessing game!" << endl;
    cout << "\t3. Exit" << endl;
    cout << setfill(sym) << setw(55);
    cout << "\n";
    cin >> choice; //The user gets to input numbers 1-3 at this point

    switch (choice)
    {
      case 1:
        //Math game here
        break;

      case 2:
        //random number game here
        break;

      case 3: //exits the program
        cout << "I guess we're done here." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I've omitted the games themselves, but I'm confused as to how to loop back to the main menu from both games after they finish. Once it finishes, I'll prompt the user "Return to menu? y/n". I suspect that I have to inset a do-while loop but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. I appreciate any advice!

Comment: how about `while(true){ ... }`

Comment: The only relevant problem with the code you've posted is that `cin >> choice` may fail if there's unexpected stuff in the stream (e.g. some alphabetic characters that can't be parsed when expecting a number)... you should really say something like `if (!(cin >> choice)) { std::cerr << "imvalid choice, terminating\n"; return EXIT_FAILURE; }`.  Your math/number game might also `exit()`, `throw` or - if embedded in `main()` and not in functions you call, set `menu` to `false` or `break` from the loop.  Try a debugger or liberally add `std::cout << "made it to line " << __LINE__ << "\n";` trace.

Comment: I see no reason why your code doesn't work and in fact it does work for me. That sort of thing usually signals a build error. Examine your compile and link procedures.

Comment: It does work! But I am supposed to add to it. What I'm trying to add is the option to return to the main menu after the game finishes; I have to prompt them: "Return to menu? y/n", etc.

Comment: `default: menu = false; break;`

Comment: @Spacebear5000: what's the point of that when option 3 is to exit anyway?  You'd be asking them twice....

Answer (score 0):

The code does exactly what you ask for! It asks the user for an option to give and then, except option 3 is given, returns back to the start of the menu.

This is because you have:

```
bool menu = true;
while (menu) {
   // your print and games
   // no modification of 'menu'
}
```

Also notice this:

```
cout << setfill(sym) << setw(55);  // 'sym' is NOT initialized here.
```

Comment: While it does print back to the menu, I want to be able to ask if the user wants to return to menu after finishing the game, or exit. Sym is declared as char sym as it prints the border for the menu; it's just decoration.. I apologize if I wasn't clear!!

Comment: It's declared but not initialized. So you want the user to be asked whether to exit or go back to the start of the menu @Spacebear5000? What exactly do you want, because from your question I understood what I wrote.